# Where can I find Umbraco free skins

Tags: umbraco, orchardcms

I am trying to compare Umbraco with Orchard, and though I could find free Orchard Skins (not many on the site) but couldn't find any for Umbraco.

And in general I looking for CMS system for my own site, what should I choose based on Professional support and ease of development (I am a .Net Developer too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much use any HTML template, but you would have to set it up yourself. This makes Umbraco pretty flexible.
Orchard is a little like DotNetNuke with its skinning capability because you can put things inside of styled "containers".

Answer (score 3):

**Update: I was wrong. There are lots of skins for Umbraco.**

I think the two CMSes are very different, with Orchard focusing on the authors and Umbraco on the developers. In other words: As far as I know there aren't any skins for Umbraco, because you are expected to choose your own layout framework. If you need skins, then choose a framework that has some.

http://www.noupe.com/css/5-popular-css-frameworks-tutorials-tools-for-getting-started.html

Comment: HI Jan! There are *tons* of Umbraco themes. Just do a Google search for "umbraco 7 themes."

Comment: You're right, there is a theme solution solution for Umbraco with the starter kit from uSkinned. They have 10 skinds to chose from, and it's 299 USD per year, though.

Comment: You should update your post because the information in it is not correct. Everyone has their personal favorites, likes and dislikes - the question is where op can find skins. uSkinned has the themes - the support is one year but the theme is for the website . a bit pricey for 5 sites , would be better if their pricing was more reasonable.

Comment: I wish there were courtesy points I could give you, as some people are not as gracious and courteous as you. I can only give you a couple ticks upward - not that points are anything. I am sure you are one of those people that others enjoy working with.